# download file with php

Tags: php, file, path, format

i want to create a link to download an excel file from the root in server computer, using php. so i wrote a simple code as below,

```
   <?php

   header("Content-disposition: attachment;     filename=example.xls");

   header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

   readfile("example.xls");

   ?>
```

it then can be downloaded however when i want to open it, i got the error saying the file i downloaded is in a different format than specified by the file extension. i also tried the same method with jpeg file and didnt get the same error but when i click it, it shows nothing. can someone help me? im not very good with programming. thank you in advance!

Comment: When I have issues like this, I usually troubleshoot them by first commenting out the `header()` functions so that I can see that it's actually sending the correct data. You can also compare example.xls on the server with the example.xls that is saved to your workstation to make sure they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $file='example.xls';  $filesize=filesize($file);
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header("Content-Length: " . $filesize);
$fh = fopen("$file, "rb");

// output file
while(!feof($fh)) 
{
# output file without bandwidth limiting
    print(fread($fh, filesize($file))); 
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: i used this in my old site for downloading nth files

Comment: thankyou for your response. i tried it but it gives error 'no data received'.

Comment: do u save the code and open it on browser on the same computer? because i want to save the code in the server computer(remotely), and download it from other computer. i think the problem is that.

Comment: @AlexButtner in header specify file name using basename() function as the code above

Comment: @AlexButtner i used the same code in my old file sharing website. it should work if you give correct file path.

Comment: Shidil, i got the same error.'the file is in a different format than specified by the file extension'. i have change the basename tho

Comment: @AlexButtner check this [link](http://mobezer.com/stack/aa.php) you see file downloading

Comment: yes, your link is working. but mine didnt. not sure why. i use the same code you gave me and even rename it according to your code. however, i still get the same error.it downloaded the file and have exactly the same file size, but the content is all messed up. for the record, my remote pc dont have microsoft office. not sure if that could be a reason.

Comment: @AlexButtner you saw the edit on answer right?, my first answer wasn't working and i don't thing it needs office installed.  one more thing- try changing content type

Comment: i try the coding below and it works!

$file = "somefile.xlsx";
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);

Comment: btw, thankyou very much @shidil for helping me. i really appreciate it! :)